# (A,B) is cointegrated while (B,A) is not cointegrated

Tags: cointegration

I'm using the Engle Granger Cointegration Method to analyse stocks and do some pairs-trading studies. While some pairs (stock A, stock B) are cointegrated with a p-value < 0.05, sometimes (stock B, stock A) returns a very high p-value.

I'm using statsmodels coint function on python.

Can anyone explain me why does this happen?